# QGIS join attributes by location python error

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

Relatively new to QGIS. Trying to add an attribute from a polygon to all the points in a shapefile (about 800 points) that are within that polygon. Used `"join attributes by location"`, point layer as the target layer, polygon layer as the join layer. I ran it and after about 20% was processed, it stopped and I received the following error:

```
TypeError: QgsFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

Looking for some troubleshooting tips on how to identify what is tripping me up here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS SE. What have you tried? Can you share us your code or data to reproduce the problem? A feature seems to have invalid geometry

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've got some null geometries in the table. Try running the "Remove null geometries" algorithm on your table before running the Join by Attributes.